# Cookie-based Forms Authentication with Cookies disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication

In my ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms Application I'm working with forms authentication, and `Cookieless` is set to `UseCookies`. The `Login` control in out web project does not display an error message if cookies are disabled in the user's browser.

Is there a way to catch this error elegantly, in order to display a nice error message to users? Just "not logging in" is a bit confusing go them, obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the answer by @Software Monkey and @thomasrutter on this post [How to detect server-side whether cookies are disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531393/how-to-detect-if-cookies-are-disabled-is-it-possible)

These are the best approaches.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there are no asp.net shipped in way to detect is cookies disabled on the client. But there are several ways to detect it 'by hand'.
 [Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410057/how-do-you-determine-cookies-are-disabled-without-javascript-and-without-red)
[example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531393/how-to-detect-if-cookies-are-disabled-is-it-possible)